# How do you skip some lines of code in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I saw some posts on this but it didn't really answer my question This is my code:

```
if os.path.exists(KEYSAVE_PATH):
    with open (KEYSAVE_PATH, "r") as file:
        data = file.readline()
    keyauthapp.login(data)

else:
    key = input('Key: ')
    keyauthapp.login(key)
    keysave = open(KEYSAVE_PATH, "w")
    n = keysave.write(key)
    keysave.close()
    /////MY CODE\\\\\
```

`/////MY CODE\\\\\` is my code basically when I run this it runs smoothly but when I get to the end of the if it just stops and ends my program there aren't any errors it just thinks its the end of my project how do I make after the `keyauthapp.login(data)` it skips to my code bellow the else statement.

Comment: You know that indentation is important in python?  If you want to leave the else bit, stop indenting.

Comment: The entire purpose of a "else" statement is to run code only when the "if" statement is *not* true. So anything in the else statement is not going to run whenever code in the if statement runs. If you want the code to run in all cases, just don't put it in the if/else.

Comment: A tangential note: In Python it is often recommended to use try-except rather than if-else (see for reference: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/idiomatic-python-eafp-versus-lbyl/.)

Comment: @Hex I attempted to make some edits to your post to improve readability by recommending some standard English protocols (Caps at beginning of sentence, periods at end of sentences). If this is helpful to you, here is another way to phrase your request : /////MY CODE\\\\\ is my code. Basically when I run this it runs smoothly but when I get to the end of the `if` it just stops and ends my program.  There are no errors.  It just thinks it is the end of my project. How do I make the code continue executing the code below the `else` after the `keyauthapp.login(data)` statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both codes in the `if-else` does the same end goal which is do the login of your app then you can unindent your code to execute when it happens either way.

```
if os.path.exists(KEYSAVE_PATH):
    with open (KEYSAVE_PATH, "r") as file:
        data = file.readline()
    keyauthapp.login(data)

else:
    key = input('Key: ')
    keyauthapp.login(key)
    keysave = open(KEYSAVE_PATH, "w")
    n = keysave.write(key)
    keysave.close()

/////MY CODE WILL BE EXECUTED WHEN LOGIN HAPPENS\\\\\
```

Comment: ty is their a shortcut to unident my big chunk of code?

Comment: Select your big chunk and do `shift` + `tab`

Comment: You could press backspace four times. From there the automatic indent will be one block less. Otherwise try pressing Ctrl + [.

Comment: Thanks Jacob TY TY TY